# How can I delete all attributes owned by a classifier in modelio?

Tags: modelio

How to remove attribute from owner in modelio?

Here is my code;

```
EList<Attribute> attributeList = classifier.getOwnedAttribute();
attributeList.removeAll(attributeList);
```

[And I got an error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6Py.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello,
Your code only **detach** the attributes from their owner, it does not delete them.

To **delete one** of them, use:

```java
classifier.getOwnedAttribute().get(0).delete();
```

If you want to **delete all** of them, use :

```java
List<Attribute> attributeList = classifier.getOwnedAttribute();
while (! attributeList.isEmpty()) {
    attributeList.get(0).delete();
}
```

Do **not** write:

```java
for (Attribute a : classifier.getOwnedAttribute()) {
    a.delete(); // <== ConcurrentModificationException on second execution
}
```

You may write instead:

```java
for (Attribute a : new ArrayList<>(classifier.getOwnedAttribute())) {
    a.delete(); // works
}
```

but it is less efficient than the first solution.